# How to fix "Fake_module : Addon missing 'bl_info' give bad performance!"

Tags: add-on

I download new Blender 2.77 RC1, when i open console, this errors show up, please help me how to fix this ???[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that you have a few non add-on python files in the following locations:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\raw_script.py
```

and

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons\tt_operators.py
```

You can tell that these files aren't add-ons because they don't include a `bl_info` somewhere at the top. A `bl_info` would look something (but not exactly like)

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Some Add-on Name",
    "author": "something",
    "version": (0, 5, 6, 6),
    "blender": (2, 7, 2)    
}
```

these are from a failed installation of the TubeTool add-on, and can be safely deleted.

Comment: Further reading: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Guidelines/Addons (can't find a better explanation)

Comment: Dont have these files at all on those paths!

Comment: Why does it give bad performance?