# Trying to install Animation Nodes - How to make Blender forget?

Tags: python, add-on, animation-nodes

I tried installing animation nodes. Blender thought it installed it but it actually didn't (because it was the windows version and I was using Linux). I realized this when I ran into [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48085/how-to-fix-fake-module-addon-missing-bl-info-give-bad-performance/64497) problem. So I deleted that zip and downloaded the linux one. Now it shows up in the Add-ons folder when I select the .zip (as shown below)
[image]

but when I click the checkbox to enable it, it gives me this error message:
[image]

Thinking that Animation Nodes is already installed, even though the Windows version didn't show up in the Add-ons panel or anywhere on my hard drive. How can I get the proper version installed?

Comment: Go to the folder for the addons and delete the wrong version. The addons can be in two places C:\\program files\\Blender Foundation\ Blender\Version\scrips\addons\ and in C:\\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\version\scripts\addons. Delete form both places and Then start blender, and install the addon again from the User Preferences using "install from file"

Comment: I'm using Linux so I don't have those locations on my hard drive. And when I do a search, I cannot find the old files.

Comment: Then look for the places where the addons are. Depending on how they are installed on your system. should be something like /home/your user/.blender or something like that. it might be a hidden folder one starting with a period before the name.

Comment: I already deleted all instances of the wrong version, as far as I can tell. Can I locate the user settings file and tell it that I don't have it installed anymore?

Comment: I think this is one of those cases where you can use File>Load Factory Settings.

Comment: Type `bpy.utils.script_paths("addons")` into the python console.  This will return a list of known addon locations. In my case `['/home/batfinger/src/BlenderGIT/kdev_build/bin/2.78/scripts/addons', '/home/batfinger/.config/blender/2.78/scripts/addons']`  Remove addon from one of these locations.  If the addon is in the blender contrib, as is animation nodes, I'd suggest removing the .config one.

Comment: @batFINGER  Hey you guys were right, there was some funky file hiding in the .config folder. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both @cegaton's and batFINGER answered this correctly. I needed to go into the .config folder found in:

```
home/user/.config/blender/2.78/scripts/addons
```

This helped blender to forget that it was installed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Click the disclosure triangle for the addon, you can find the path to the addon file in the info there.

[image: addon path]

Comment: Thanks! batFINGER's comment solved it. I appreciate the help.